# how to know which language apps written in

Tags: android, mobile

I want to make an application and I need to know the programming languages that were used in similar applications in google play store. I tried to contact the owners of the application but there is no response.

> i tried to see the app files using file manager but didn't work.

Comment: If it's not open source, why would they have any obligation to tell anyone?

Comment: What did you see after decompiling the app classes

Comment: @caladeve Because its applications to help people and  Nonprofit as my application

Comment: @AshokKumar thank you 'decompiling' was the answer

Comment: @suhaibsalem Glad that helped you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is decompile apk and you can see java, c++ or other lang.

Answer (score 0):

If you will describe the app that you're trying to create, some people here may be able to make suggestions.  In general though, android apps are written in either Java or Kotlin.  If you're just starting out, start with Java.